# SpeechRecognitionEngine in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, speech-recognition, sapi

I am trying to write a C# application using Windows Forms and System.Speech to convert a WAV file to text.  I've seen plenty of samples online of how to do this, but none that are very robust.  I was hoping to write an application that could parse smaller pieces of a large WAV file using BackgroundWorker threads, but I keep getting the following exception in my threads' DoWork function when it calls engine.Recognize():

"No audio input is supplied to this recognizer. Use the method SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice if a microphone is connected to the system, otherwise use SetInputToWaveFile, SetInputToWaveStream or SetInputToAudioStream to perform speech recognition from pre-recorded audio"

Here is the code in my DoWork() function:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new    System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
engine.SetInputToWaveFile(fname);
engine.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
engine.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
engine.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
engine.EndSilenceTimeoutAmbiguous = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
engine.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);

BackgroundWorker w = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
while (true)
{    
RecognitionResult data = engine.Recognize();
if (data == null)
    break;
if (w == null) //our thread died from beneath us
    break;
if (!w.IsBusy) //our thread died from beneath us
    break;
if (w.CancellationPending) //notice to cancel
    break;
w.ReportProgress(0, data.Text);
}
```

I am launching multiple BackgroundWorker threads that run this code.  If i use a single thread, I don't see this problem.

Comment: I haven't working with sapi in years, but off the top of my head, I remember they could run as single out of process com servers, so if your trying to get multiples to work simultanously, that's not the default scenario and you would have to have shared audio sources and in process recognizers.

Comment: I've noticed that trying to use the SpeechRecognitionEngine class at all from a BackgroundWorker thread causes this exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach. I tested it for Console and Windows Forms application types.

```
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var r1 = new Recognizer(@"c:\proj\test.wav");
        r1.Completed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(r1.Result.Text);

        var r2 = new Recognizer(@"c:\proj\test.wav");
        r2.Completed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(r2.Result.Text);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Recognizer {
    private readonly string _fileName;
    private readonly AsyncOperation _operation;
    private volatile RecognitionResult _result;

    public Recognizer(string fileName) {
        _fileName = fileName;
        _operation = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);            
        _result = null;

        var worker = new Action(Run);
        worker.BeginInvoke(delegate(IAsyncResult result) {
            worker.EndInvoke(result);
        }, null);            
    }

    private void Run() {
        try {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
            engine.SetInputToWaveFile(_fileName);
            engine.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
            engine.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
            engine.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
            engine.EndSilenceTimeoutAmbiguous = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
            engine.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
            _result = engine.Recognize();
        }
        finally {
            _operation.PostOperationCompleted(delegate {
                RaiseCompleted();
            }, null);
        }
    }

    public RecognitionResult Result {
        get { return _result; }
    }

    public event EventHandler Completed;

    protected virtual void OnCompleted(EventArgs e) {
        if (Completed != null)
            Completed(this, e);
    }

    private void RaiseCompleted() {
        OnCompleted(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I played with this code this morning and I think this will work - although I don't really understand why if indeed the SpeechRecognitionEngine can't be multi-threaded.  One question I have - it appears the Completed event handler runs in the context of another thread, so I can't update the UI.  Could you modify your example to invoke the callbacks on the calling (UI) thread?

Comment: I used the code described here and got it to work. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11848/Another-way-to-Invoke-UI-from-a-Worker-Thread

Comment: One final question - what is the best way to cancel these asynchronous operations if the Windows Form is closed in the middle of operations?